# Javascript Object Response

Tags: javascript, json, get

I am calling a RESTful web service using the http-https node package. Code below:

```
var request = http.get(url, function(resp){
   console.log(resp);       
});
request.end();
```

However, when I examine what is held in the variable `resp`, it comes back as `[Object]`. When I ask for `resp.toString()`, I get `[object Object]'. I know that the service is returning me JSON, and I know the structure of the JSON. However, I am unsure why I am getting this response back instead of JSON.

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));`. Look at headers also for clues as to "why". Note that `{}.toString()` returns `[object Object]` ... that is expected

Comment: Maybe you getting a direct decoded JSON.

Comment: Ok I was able to examine the headers, and can confirm that it is 200. However, the res portion has `res: [Circular]`. This is where I was expecting my JSON to be. Also two other important header fields: `'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'`. Would this cause any problems if I am not parsing anything after I get the response?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because,

1)You are getting array [], not the object in response.

2)If you are sure that you are getting object in response, then alert(JSON.stringify(response)) to generate string from response object and also makesure object is non empty.